# Is stochastic GARCH-M a stochastic volatility model?

Tags: garch

https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/archive/discussion-paper/a-note-on-the-estimation-of-grach-m-models-using-the-kalman-filter defines a stochastic GARCH-M model for returns $r_t$ as follows:

$r_t = \alpha' x_t + \delta h^2_t + \epsilon_t \quad \epsilon_t|\Omega_{t-1} \sim N(0, h^2_t)$

$h^2_t = A_0 + \sum^{p}_{i=1} A_i \epsilon^2_{t-i} + \sum^{q}_{j=1} B_j h^2_{t-j} + \omega_t \quad \omega_t \sim N(0, Q_t)$

Does this sort of model fall into the stochastic volatility class of models?

Comment: I suppose it does because the conditional variance equation contains a stochastic error term $w$.

Comment: But then is $h^2_t$ not known at the start of time $t$?

Comment: That would be strange. I suppose $\omega$ should have a time index $t$? If we are operating in discrete time, there is no "start" or "end" of time $t$, it is just a single instance.

Comment: $\omega$ should have a time index $t$. Thank you, I've made the edit. But now that this adjustment has been made does it mean $h^2_t \not \in \Omega_{t-1}$?

Comment: What is $\Omega_{t-1}$?

Comment: This is the information set or $\sigma$-algebra containing all information known up to and including time $t-1$. If I can be more precise, we can say that $\Omega_{t-1} := \sigma(\{ r_0, \dots, r_{t-1}\})$

Comment: Given this, your previous comments seems to be correct.